# Can Euro 2016 tickets be transferred to a someone

Tags: uefa, euro

I have 2 tickets for a match on my name. I'd like to bring a friend with me. At the stadium entrance I suspect there will be an ID check. We will not arrive at the same time.

Are you allowed to enter the stadium with a ticket on someone's else name?
In case you are accompanied with the tickets owner (call him nameA), can a person holding a ticket for nameA enter? 
I just hope you don't have to resell through the portal and rebuy it again.

I went through the FAQ of EURO 2016, it isn't clear.
http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro-finals/ticketing/faq/index.html

Hope others in the same situation will find this useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Euro 2016 customer services. If they're not responding to questions, we're not going to be able to help either.

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer a ticket to a guest, but must go into the stadium together. From the [terms and conditions](http://www.uefa.com/multimediafiles/download/competitions/ticketing/02/34/70/67/2347067_download.pdf):

> 8.2. The Successful Buyer shall be permitted to transfer the Ticket(s) to her/his Guest(s) (if applicable) provided that (jointly):
>
> 1. the Successful Buyer will attend the Match together with her/his Guest(s)
> 2. the Tickets are for their personal use;
> 3. such transfer is free of any additional charges above face value

Unless you go into the stadium together, in the event of being caught in an ID Check, your friend would have no way of proving that he will be watching the match together with you.

So the safest way would be to meet at an agreed place close to the stadium and go in to the stadium together. Assuming you are both going to be there in time for the kick-off, surely this is possible.